# Trigger dispatch inside useEffect only once

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this component where i need to trigger the `dispatch` only once inside the `useEffect` whenever there is a change in `addressList` (same as when either of `handleAddNewShippingAddress` or `handleEditShippingAddress` or `handleEditShippingAddress` are triggered which causes a change in the `addressList`). If i pass `addressList` into the dependency list, it runs into an infinite loop, hence i stringified the addressList and passed it into dependency. This approach is sometimes causing extra requests to the backend. How can i achieve without doing this approach and trigger `useEffect` only once upon change in `addressList`?

```
function ShippingAddress() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { isLoading, addressList, error } = useSelector(state => state.address)

    const addressListString = JSON.stringify(addressList)
    console.log(addressListString)

    useEffect(() => {
        // Triggers GET request
        dispatch(getShippingAddressList())
    }, [dispatch, addressListString])
    
    // Triggers POST request
    const handleAddNewShippingAddress = (newAddressData) => {
        dispatch(addShippingAddress(newAddressData))
    }
    
    // Triggers PUT request
    const handleEditShippingAddress = (formData, shippingAddressId) => {
        dispatch(editShippingAddress(formData, shippingAddressId))
    }
        
    // Triggers DELETE request
    const handleRemoveShippingAddress = (shippingAddressId) => {
        dispatch(removeShippingAddress(shippingAddressId))
    }
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            ...
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: `addressListString` is not used inside the `useEffect`, why is `getShipppingAddressList` dependent on it? It sounds like the `add/edit/remove` actions should be [Redux Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) that refetch the address after it is modified. This should not be handled in a React component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should likely move out of React. Your actions could be [Redux Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) that handle the sequence of external requests.

```js
export function getShippingAddressList() { /* … */ }

export function addShippingAddress(newAddressData) {
  return async (dispatch, /* getState */) => {
    await doApiCallToAddShippingAddress(newAddressData);
    dispatch(getShippingAddressList());
  };
}

export function editShippingAddress(formData, shippingAddressId) {
  return async (dispatch, /* getState */) => {
    await doApiCallToEditShippingAddress(formData, shippingAddressId);
    dispatch(getShippingAddressList());
  };
}

export function removeShippingAddress(shippingAddressId) {
  return async (dispatch, /* getState */) => {
    await doApiCallToRemoveShippingAddress(shippingAddressId);
    dispatch(getShippingAddressList());
  };
}
```